# How can I use with() method and where() method using nested columns?

Tags: php, yii2

There is a structure like this:

Entity1 has many Entity2 that has many Entity3

I want to get all entities of Entity3 that are associated with one entity of Entity1.

In SQL it would be something like:

```
 SELECT Entity3.*
    FROM Entity3
    INNER JOIN Entity2 on Entitity3.entity2_id = Entity2.id
    INNER JOIN Entity1 on Entity2.entity1_id = Entity1.id
    WHERE
        Entity1.id = X;
```

Comment: you'll need to get creative with php and do quite a few mysql queries. Make sure you use the `GROUP BY` syntax to shorten the number of queries though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a way, as it follows:

```
$entities3 = Entity3::find()->joinWith(['entity2.entity1'])->where('entity2.entity1_id='.$entity1_id)->all();
```

Answer (score 4):

In Entity1 model:

```
public function getEntities2()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Entity2::className(), ['id' => 'entity2_id']);
}

public function getEntities3()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Entity3::className(), ['id' => 'entity3_id'])->via('entities2');
}
```

Comment: Fabrizio, but how would that work having the PK of entity1 as a variable? I mean, I want something like getEntity3ByEntity1($entity1_id), do you know what I mean?